# Angular 5 fullscreen single div container

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a grid inside a div. I am able to enter fullscreen using a function but I am looking to just make the div with the grid in it full So far all I have been able to find is limited to making the entire web page fullscreen. This is what I have.

```
    <a (click)="openFullscreen()"title="Full Screen" style="padding-right: 5px"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i></a>
    <div class="row">
            <grid>
                stuff
           </grid>
        </div>
```

TS

```
openFullscreen() {
    if (this.elem.requestFullscreen) {
      this.elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      /* Firefox */
      this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
      this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (this.elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
      /* IE/Edge */
      this.elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
  }
```

///////////////EDITS//////////////

TS

```
  @ViewChild('fullScreen') divRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.divRef = document.documentElement;        
  }

openFullscreen() {
    if (this.divRef.requestFullscreen) {
      this.divRef.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (this.divRef.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      /* Firefox */
      this.divRef.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (this.divRef.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
      this.divRef.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (this.divRef.msRequestFullscreen) {
      /* IE/Edge */
      this.divRef.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
    <a (click)="openFullscreen()"title="Full Screen" style="padding-right: 5px"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"></i></a>
    <div class="well" #fullScreen>
        <grid>
             stuff
        </grid>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set a [template variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) to the element you want to make fullscreen:

```
<a (click)="openFullscreen()" title="Full Screen"> Toggle fullscreen </a>
<div class="row" #fullScreen>
   <grid>
       stuff
   </grid>
</div>
```

then in your component you can get a reference to that element using the [View Child decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) and execute the function you already have:

```
@ViewChild('fullScreen') divRef;

openFullscreen() {
  // Use this.divRef.nativeElement here to request fullscreen
  const elem = this.divRef.nativeElement;

  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

Comment: I made a edit to the code but its still not going full screen on just the div. Still doing the entire web page. See edits above.

Comment: Because you are assigning document.documentElement in the ngOnInit. Remove that line of code and it will work, ViewChild will query the dom by itself.

Comment: @MassimilianoSartoretto Why did not you post full example and hide some part?

Comment: @hexadecimal updated. I didn't hide anything, the remaining code was part of the question. Now the answer is complete.

Comment: @MassimilianoSartoretto It's better now, thanks... Voted up ;)

Answer (score 0):

For more recent angular versions:

```
@ViewChild('fullScreen',{static: false}) divRef;
```